# C++ TCP based Server socket takes time to return 10054 error. Its doesn't return immediately

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, tcp

I have linux based TCP client  written in C and Server written in c++ and deployed on Windows machine.

1. From Server, I am sending 1 byte of data every 5 seconds.
2. Client receives it.
3. After disconnecting internet on client when I look at the log of Server it takes a **lot of time to return error 10054 on Server** on send.
4. Its a multi socket and multithread based windows service.

what should I do to get error immediately ??

Comment: You can't do anything to get the error immediately. There is a lot of buffering between you and the receiver, which practically guarantees you won't get the connection reset on the first send after the peer disconnects.

Comment: how can we reduce this delay?? Can it be done by  increasing or decreasing  the time interval of sending data.?

Comment: The usual way around this is to have a ping/pong - the client sends a reply when it receives data from the server.  If the client hasn't replied within a certain time, assume it's become disconnected and close the connection.

Comment: @MrZebra. Surprise!!!! there is no elegant way to handle this condition. I am also planning to put time out on server side.

Comment: Yep, this is part of the robustness of TCP though - if you plug the internet connection back in, it'll carry on as if nothing had happened

Comment: If it is important for the server to detect the lost client in a timely manner, and you cannot change your protocol to account for it, then you can turn on TCP keep-alives, at least. On Windows, you can tweak the timeout intervals using the [`SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd877220.aspx) control code of [`WSAIoctl()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741621.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

are you closing the connection on client-side before cutting down the internet?

If the client just stops responding to the server (`After disconnecting internet`), the TCP-socket on both-sides will close the connection after the `timeout` has expired. This is the default-behaviour of TCP. 
The `timeout` can be modified, but its better to close the connection correctly and keep the `timeout` unmodified

Comment: If he is disconnecting the Internet on the client side it doesn't make any difference whether he is closing the connection on the client side or not, and there is no way the client can respond after the Internet is disconnected. Answer doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Domso . Are you also suggesting to put time out on server? I couldn't understand your answer

Comment: @EJP its normal for having a delay after cutting down a connection. (timeout), but it does make a difference, if you close the connection before you cut down the internet. If you really want to reduce the delay, you can adjust the TCP-timeout

Comment: @Domso Of course it makes a difference, but if you close the connection before cutting the Internet there is really nothing to cut, and the OP's question does not arise.

Comment: @EJP yes, thats why I asked it - to clarify whether the connection was closed or not.  But the second part of my answer answers his question.